# how to create private chat between two users with socket.io and sailsjs

Tags: socket.io, sails.js

i create something like chat,i know how to send messages to all user in room with(sails.sockets.broadcast(...e.m)) but can't understand how to send message to one user(i think chat between 2 users), when second user send message to first user, first get the message sended by second, but when i create 3 users, and when third user send message to first - the second users too get the message, how can i do this.
Who knows how to do it?

Answer (score 4):

Socket.io has rooms built in. You could do something like:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.join('some room');
});
```

and then call it with :

```
io.to('some room').emit('some event');
```

Alternatively, you could pass in an object along with the emit on your server side, and then on your client side, check to see if that object exists. For example:

```
var obj = {
    shouldDisplay: someIDhere
}

socket.emit('yourEvent', obj);
```

And then check if the incoming event's object has the ID if the user you want to display the message